# How to build a complex view?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I build a view like this?

Maybe first row image and then another image for the spinner and then button for the preference and then button for the email.

Second row: two buttons with two images.

Is there a simple way?

[image: the desired view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple ActionBar pattern. Please refer to the [ActionBar API documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) in the Android docs, and the [ActionBarSherlock](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock) library which will allow you to use this back to 2.1